# React Security on state management

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Let's say that I have this code:

```
const UserProfile: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = (props) => {

    const { isAdmin} = useContext(GlobalContext);

    if (isAdmin()) {
      return <CriticalFeature/>;
    } else {
    return <NonCriticalFeature/>;
    }

}

export default UserProfile;
```

The problem with this code is that someone can open the react web page and take a look at that state and change it (with the default  react tools for example). Then the user is going to act as an admin (i know... not on the server side due the authentication, but still is going to see at least some code from admin page).

how do you handle this situation?

Comment: Server side validation.

Comment: I suggest googling `react authentication and authorization` and looking at some of the tutorials that come up.

Answer (score 2):

If you allowed the browser to fetch the code that renders / handles the `CriticalFeature`, the game is over. The user can render or otherwise analyze that code.

The only way around this is to never serve the code of `CriticalFeature` to an unauthorized user. For that, the URL of the admin profile page should be different than that of a non-admin user, and the code for `CriticalFeature` should be in a separate bundle which is only served to authorized users.

IDK if you need this level of separation, though; a glimpse of an admin UI will not let the unauthorized user to *do* anything requiring admin privileges. Only if you need to closely guard the set of features available to admins you might want to implement the above.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that somebody could modify the state and render the CriticalFeature component but in this case is best practice to have authenticated requests to the backend.

So even when somebody can render the component they cannot impersonate an admin profile in the server.

Just make sure that you have a proper auth in place